# iPhone jquery/ajax only works for some instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mobile-safari

I have multiple pages across a project I am working on that use AJAX to submit a form to django.  All of these buttons work on seemingly everything (mobile and desktop, chrome, firefox, desktop safari) except for mobile safari.  Using safari on an iPhone, some of the requests will work, but others won't and I can't seem to figure out why.  I have tried to make them all in a similar structure to the one that works, but still, nothing so I figured I'd ask for some help.  Thank you in advance!

Here is a working example:

Javascript:

```
$('#submit').on('click',function(){
        dataDict = {csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{ csrf_token }}'};
        dataDict['deleted_exercises'] = deleted_exercises;
        var errors = 0;
        $('.error').hide();
        dataDict['workout_id'] = '{{ workout.id }}';
        var exist_exercise_list = [];
        $('.existing').each(function(){
            //add either new or existing exercise name to exercise list
            var ex_name = $(this).find('.ex-name').data('name');
            var edit_ex_name_input = $(this).find('.ex-name-input').val(); 
            var ex_name_lower = ex_name.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
            exist_exercise_list.push(ex_name);

            var edit_ex_name = ex_name_lower + '-name';
            dataDict[edit_ex_name] = edit_ex_name_input;

            //add exercise unit to data dict
            var edit_ex_unit = $(this).find('.ex-unit').val();
            var ex_unit_name = ex_name_lower + '-unit';
            dataDict[ex_unit_name] = edit_ex_unit;

            //add max event for exercise to data dict
            var max_event = $(this).find('.max-event-select').val();
            var max_event_name = ex_name_lower + '-max-event';
            dataDict[max_event_name] = max_event;

            //add color group to data dict
            var color_group = $(this).find('.ex-color-select').val();
            var color_group_name = ex_name_lower + '-color';
            dataDict[color_group_name] = color_group;

            //add exercise order to dataDict
            var exercise_order = $(this).data('order');
            var order_name = ex_name_lower + '-order';
            dataDict[order_name] = exercise_order;

            //add exercise notes
            var notes = $(this).find('.ex-notes').val();
            var notes_name = ex_name_lower + '-notes';
            dataDict[notes_name] = notes;

            //
            var sets = $(this).find('.exist-set');
            var num_sets = $(sets).length;
            var num_sets_name = ex_name_lower + '-num-sets';
            dataDict[num_sets_name] = num_sets;
            $(sets).each(function(){
                var set_num = $(this).find('.set-num').data('number');

                //add target weight for this set to dataDict
                var target_weight = $(this).find('.weight').val();
                if (target_weight != '' && Math.round(target_weight) !== parseInt(target_weight)){
                    errors = errors + 1;
                    $(this).find('.weight').before("<span class='error' style='color: #FF4444'>Please enter a valid weight</span>");
                }
                var target_weight_name = ex_name_lower + '-set-' + set_num + '-weight';
                dataDict[target_weight_name] = target_weight;

                //add max percentage to dataDict
                var max_percent = $(this).find('.percentage').val();
                if (max_percent != '' && isNaN(max_percent)){
                    errors = errors + 1;
                    $(this).find('.percentage').before("<span class='error' style='color: #FF4444'>Please enter a valid percent</span>");
                }
                var max_percent_name = ex_name_lower + '-set-' + set_num + '-percent';
                dataDict[max_percent_name] = max_percent;

                //add reps to dataDict
                var reps = $(this).find('.reps').val();
                if (reps != '' && Math.round(reps) !== parseInt(reps)){
                    errors = errors + 1;
                    $(this).find('.reps').before("<span class='error' style='color: #FF4444'>Please enter a valid rep number</span>");
                }
                var reps_name = ex_name_lower + '-set-' + set_num + '-reps';
                dataDict[reps_name] = reps;
            })

            var added_sets_list = [];
            var added_sets = $(this).find('.new-set');
            $(added_sets).each(function(){
                var set_num = $(this).find('.set-num').data('number');
                var target_weight = $(this).find('.target-weight-input').val();
                if (target_weight != '' && Math.round(target_weight) !== parseInt(target_weight)){
                    errors = errors + 1;
                    $(this).find('.target-weight-input').before("<span class='error' style='color: #FF4444'>Please enter a valid weight</span>");
                }
                var max_percent = $(this).find('.max-percent').val();
                if (max_percent != '' && isNaN(max_percent)){
                    errors = errors + 1;
                    $(this).find('.max-percent').before("<span class='error' style='color: #FF4444'>Please enter a valid percent</span>")
                }

                var reps = $(this).find('.reps').val();
                if (reps == '' || Math.round(reps) !== parseInt(reps)){
                    errors = errors + 1;
                    $(this).find('.reps').before("<span class='error' style='color: #FF4444'>Please enter a valid rep number</span>");
                }

                var add_set = set_num + '_-&&-_' + target_weight + '_-&&-_' + max_percent + '_-&&-_' + reps;
                added_sets_list.push(add_set);
            })
            var added_sets_name = ex_name_lower + '-added-sets';
            dataDict[added_sets_name] = added_sets_list;

        })

        var new_exercises = [];
        $('.new-ex').each(function(){
            var new_ex_name = $(this).find('.new-ex-name').val();
            if (new_ex_name == ''){
                errors = errors + 1;
                $(this).find('.new-ex-name').before("<span class='error' style='color: #FF4444'>Please enter an exercise name</span>")
            }
            new_exercises.push(new_ex_name);
            var new_ex_name_lower = new_ex_name.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();

            var new_ex_order = $(this).data('order');
            var new_ex_order_name = new_ex_name_lower + '-order-new';
            dataDict[new_ex_order_name] = new_ex_order;

            var new_ex_unit = $(this).find('.new-ex-unit').val();
            var new_ex_unit_name = new_ex_name_lower + '-unit-new';
            dataDict[new_ex_unit_name] = new_ex_unit;

            var new_ex_max_event = $(this).find('.new-ex-max-event').val();
            var new_ex_max_event_name = new_ex_name_lower + '-max-event-new';
            dataDict[new_ex_max_event_name] = new_ex_max_event;

            var new_ex_color = $(this).find('.new-ex-color-select').val();
            var new_ex_color_name = new_ex_name_lower + '-color-new';
            dataDict[new_ex_color_name] = new_ex_color;

            var new_ex_notes = $(this).find('.new-ex-notes').val();
            var new_ex_notes_name = new_ex_name_lower + '-notes-new';
            dataDict[new_ex_notes_name] = new_ex_notes;

            var new_ex_sets = $(this).find('.set');
            var num_set_new = $(new_ex_sets).length;
            var num_set_new_name = new_ex_name_lower + '-num-sets-new';
            dataDict[num_set_new_name] = num_set_new;

            $(new_ex_sets).each(function(){
                var set_num = $(this).find('.set-num').data('number');
                var weight = $(this).find('.target-weight-input').val();
                if (weight != '' && Math.round(weight) !== parseInt(weight)){
                    errors = errors + 1;
                    $(this).find('.target-weight-input').before("<span class='error' style='color: #FF4444'>Please enter a valid weight</span>");
                }
                var weight_name = new_ex_name_lower + '-set-' + set_num + '-weight-new';
                dataDict[weight_name] = weight;

                var percent = $(this).find('.max-percent').val();
                if (percent != '' && isNaN(percent)){
                    errors = errors + 1;
                    $(this).find('.max-percent').before("<span class='error' style='color: #FF4444'>Please enter a valid percentage</span>");
                }
                var percent_name = new_ex_name_lower + '-set-' + set_num + '-percent-new';
                dataDict[percent_name] = percent;

                var reps = $(this).find('.reps').val();
                if (reps == '' || Math.round(reps) !== parseInt(reps)){
                    errors = errors + 1;
                    $(this).find('.reps').before("<span class='error' style='color: #FF4444'>Please enter a valid rep number</span>");
                }
                var reps_name = new_ex_name_lower + '-set-' + set_num + '-reps-new';
                dataDict[reps_name] = reps;

            })
        })
        dataDict['removed_sets'] = removed_sets;
        dataDict['deleted_exercises'] = deleted_exercises;
        dataDict['existing_exercises'] = exist_exercise_list;
        dataDict['new_exercises'] = new_exercises;

        if (errors == 0){
            $.ajax({
                url: "/edit_athlete_workout/",
                type: 'POST',
                data: dataDict,
                success : function() {
                            window.location.reload(true);
                    },
                error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                    $('#result').append("<div class='alert-box alert radius' data-alert>Oops! We have encountered an error: "+errmsg+
                    " <a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>"); // add the error to the dom
                    console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
                }
            });
        }

    })
```

Button:

```
<button class='btn' id='submit' type='button'>Submit</button>
```

And one that doesn't work:

```
$('#complete-wo').on('click',function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    results = {csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{ csrf_token }}'};
    $('.errorDesc').remove();
    var ex_ids = [];
    var errors = 0;
    results['exercises'] = ex_ids;

    $('.ex-id').each(function(i, obj){
        var exercise_id = $(obj).val()
        ex_ids.push(exercise_id);
        var reps_comp = $('input[name="reps-ex-'+ exercise_id + '"').val();
        if (reps_comp == '' || Math.round(reps_comp) !== parseInt(reps_comp)){
            errors = errors + 1;
            $('input[name="reps-ex-'+ exercise_id + '"').before('<div class="errorDesc" style="color: #FF0000"> Enter a valid rep number</div>');
        }
        var load_comp = $('input[name="load-ex-'+ exercise_id + '"').val();
        if (load_comp == '' || Math.round(load_comp) !== parseInt(load_comp)){
            errors = errors + 1;
            $('input[name="load-ex-'+ exercise_id + '"').before('<div class="errorDesc" style="color: #FF0000"> Enter a valid weight</div>');
        }
        results['reps-ex-' + exercise_id] = reps_comp;
        results['load-ex-' + exercise_id] = load_comp;
        //alert(exercise_id + '/' + results['reps-ex-' + exercise_id] + results['load-ex-' + exercise_id]);
    })
    if (errors == 0){
        $.ajax({
                url: "/submit_workout/",
                type: 'POST',
                data: results,
                success : function() {
                            window.location.href = '/player_calendar/';
                    },
                error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                    $('#result').append("<div class='alert-box alert radius' data-alert>Oops! We have encountered an error: "+errmsg+
                    " <a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>"); // add the error to the dom
                    console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
                }
            });
    }

});
```

Button:

```
<button class='btn btn-primary btn-block' id='complete-wo' type='button'>Workout Complete</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem.  For some reason, on mobile safari, there was a problem with selecting the inputs using:

```
var reps_comp = $('input[name="reps-ex-'+ exercise_id + '"').val();
load_comp = $('input[name="load-ex-'+ exercise_id + '"').val();
```

The page worked fine once I switched these to just be class-based selectors.